# Simple_form textarea resize: vertically

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I have a simple form that I want to be able to resize vertically, not horizontally. My CSS isn't passing through to the form and I was wondering if there was an error in my code or a workaround needed for simple_form, thanks!

CSS:

```
/* CONTACT */
.general-contact { min-height: 390px;}
#contactTextarea { margin-bottom: ; }
#contactTextarea > textarea {
border: 1px inset #333333;
background-color: #242323;
color: #E0E0E0;
resize: vertical;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="panel-body general-contact">
  <%= simple_form_for(@contact, url: contact_path) do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.input :email, :required => false, class: "form-control" %>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.input :subject, :required => false, class: "form-control" %>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group hidden">
      <%= f.input :nickname, :hint => "leave this field blank!", class: "form-control" %>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group" id="contactTextarea">
      <%= f.input :message, :as => :text, :input_html => {:rows => 5}, class: "form-control" %>
    </div>
      <%= f.submit "Send message!", class: "btn btn-success" %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of what it looks like now and explain more what is wrong? If you view page source can you see the CSS file being loaded?

Comment: The CSS file is definitely loading, When I go to resize the textarea it can be dragged on the horizontal axis when I only want it to be dragged vertically. I think it stopped working after I replaced standard rails form with simple_form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a go at using the Simple Form's `wrapper_html` option, rather than using your own divs. Simple Form auto-generates the wrapper, so it might be your text area is getting nested further than expected.

From their [docs](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form):

> Since Simple Form generates a wrapper div around your label and input by default, you can pass any html attribute to that wrapper as well using the :wrapper_html option, like so:

```
<%= simple_form_for @user do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :username, wrapper_html: { class: 'username' } %>
  <%= f.input :password, wrapper_html: { id: 'password' } %>
  <%= f.input :remember_me, wrapper_html: { class: 'options' } %>
  <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

Therefore, you should be able to use the line:

```
<%= f.input :message, :as => :text, :input_html => {:rows => 5}, class: "form-control", wrapper_html: { id: 'contactTextarea' } %>
```

Let me know how you get on with that / any questions you have!